# Derivation of solution for simple control problem

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control, adaptive-control, model-predictive-control

While trying to understand the fundamental concepts in control theory reading the following article [Dual Control
for Approximate Bayesian Reinforcement Learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.03591.pdf)
(chapter 3.1, "A toy problem") i came across the following solutions to a very simple problem:

Consider the linear, scalar system:

$x_{k+1} = ax_k + bu_k + \xi_k$

Where as $x_k$ denotes the state at timestep $k$, $u_k$ the control action at timestep $k$ and $\xi$ is normally distributed.

Consider the following cost function: $L(x, u) = [\sum_{k=0}^T (x_k - r_k)^T W_k (x_k - r_k) + \sum_{k=0}^{T-1}u_k^TU_ku_k]$
where as $r = [r_0...r_T]$ is a target trayectory. $W_k$ and $U_k$ define state and control cost respectively.

If $a$ and $b$ are known, the optimal $u_k$ to drive the current state $x_k$ to zero in one step can be trivially verified to be $u_{k, oracle}^* = -\frac{abx_k}{U + b^2}$

Let now parameter $b$ be uncertain, with current belief $p(b) \sim N(b; u_k, \alpha_k^2)$ at time $k$. The naive option of simply replacing the parameter with the current mean estimate is known as certainty equivalence (CE) control in the dual control literature. The resulting control law is $u_{k, ce}^* = -\frac{au_kx_k}{U + u_k^2}$

---

How can i derive these solutions?

Comment: Your post is still unclear and contains a lot of typos. In any way, $U$ is defined in the paper and is part of the cost to be optimized $\mathcal{L}(x,u)$. The optimal control laws are found by explicitly solving for this optimization problem.

Comment: @KBS i edited it now and changed the question a bit. How do i derive these solutions?

Comment: Your statement is Ricatti's optimal control of multivariable linear systems. Take a look at https://www.kybernetika.cz/content/1972/5/430/paper.pdf. Uncertain systems will have similar solutions except for consideration of respective constraints.

Comment: This paper is pretty sloppy when it comes to this example. The terminal cost is missing and this control law does not drive the state to zero in one step. A simple substitution shows that. This is only true when $U=0$. In any way, if you want to retrieve this solution you will need to consider the discrete-time finite-horizon LQR problem with terminal cost $x_1^Tx_1$ and use the formulas there: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear%E2%80%93quadratic_regulator

Comment: @Bruno Lobo : The paper at your link was really nice and got me into checking out more of kushner's material. He writes really beautifully ( I'm trying to self-study this field of optimal control in spare time and it's large and broad and not easy. So finding someone who is clear and in the right sub-fields is so great ) so I decided to buy his old book. It just arrived and I took a glance and it looks really amazing for me as far as the topics it covers. As you know, there are many different optimal control topics. So, thank you for your link and the kushner finding.